# Find duplicate value and replace them with unique values using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my source xml: How can i check Element-4 for duplicate values and replace the duplicate value to make them unique?

```
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
     <Element-4>1234</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00378</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>4321</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00378</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00666</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>BB</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>5678</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>8765</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>AA</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00666</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00666</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>BB</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
```

How can I find the duplicate values? In the above xsl it will be 00378 and 00666.
Keep the first value and replace the second with unique value like 00378A, third vlue with 00378B and so on.
The expected result would be:

```
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
     <Element-4>1234</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00378</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>4321</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00378A</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00666</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>BB</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>5678</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>8765</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>AA</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00666A</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
<Segment-PO> 
     <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
     <Element-4>00666B</Element-4> 
     <Element-5>BB</Element-5>          
</Segment-PO>
```

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or above?

Answer (score 1):

One way (probably not the most efficient, but easy) is to count the preceding elements with the same value. You can use `xsl:number` to format as a letter.

Example...

**XML Input** (wrapped in `doc` to make well formed)

```
<doc>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
        <Element-4>1234</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
        <Element-4>00378</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
        <Element-4>4321</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
        <Element-4>00378</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
        <Element-4>00666</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>BB</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
        <Element-4>5678</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
        <Element-4>8765</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>AA</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
        <Element-4>00666</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
    <Segment-PO> 
        <Element-3>IN</Element-3> 
        <Element-4>00666</Element-4> 
        <Element-5>BB</Element-5>          
    </Segment-PO>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Element-4">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:if test="preceding::Element-4[.=current()]">
        <xsl:number value="count(preceding::Element-4[.=current()])" format="A"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>1234</Element-4>
      <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>00378</Element-4>
      <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>4321</Element-4>
      <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>00378A</Element-4>
      <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>00666</Element-4>
      <Element-5>BB</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>5678</Element-4>
      <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>8765</Element-4>
      <Element-5>AA</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>00666A</Element-4>
      <Element-5>ZZ</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
   <Segment-PO>
      <Element-3>IN</Element-3>
      <Element-4>00666B</Element-4>
      <Element-5>BB</Element-5>
   </Segment-PO>
</doc>
```

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzU